# twitter bootstrap: what files to include

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

OK. I am a little confused.  I downloaded the bootstrap v2 and noticed that the .css file does not contain "topbar" or "fill" classes. but I see several examples using these classes.

Also,  What is the required files to include to have the framework working?  Do I just need th one bootstrap.css file?

What about the bootstrap.js file? Do I need to include that too?

```
 <div class="navbar">
    <div class="fill">

        <div class="container">
            <div > <a class="brand pull-left" href="">Product</a></div>

            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="index.html">Create Account</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="index.html">Forgot Password</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="index.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My menu is on the left side. I want it in the middle so it lines up with the main body content. I thought wrapping a "container" would do this...

Comment: Did you download a modified version of the bootstrap from their download page? Or the complete version from GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"topbar" or "fill" are not standard classes in bootstrap. You should use some kinds of modified version or just use class "navbar" "navbar-fixed-top" "navbar-fixed-bottom" ...

Comment: what is bootstrap.js? is that needed?

Comment: Bootstrap.js is bootstrap's javascript for some jQuery plugins. If you need these plugins like modal, tooltips ... ( there are 12 plugins available on bootstrap's official website). As my experiment, you should us these plugins for high interactive, clean and clear interface sites.

Comment: so to use the modal plugin I just need to include: bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js along with jquery.js right?  Also would you know why my navbar is on the far left side instead of in the middle?  I'll post my html in my question.

Comment: Yep, just attach bootstrap.css, bootstrap.js, jquery.js with your page and follow some markups. You can read about the markups on bootstrap site. About your nav, you can make your div.fill width up to 100% and then the container align center.

Answer (score 7):

Most parts of Twitter bootstrap only require that you include the CSS-file. There are however some additional things that might be required.

If you want to use the glyph-icons, you need upload the image-sprites for those.

If you want to use any of the jQuery-plugins (carousel, tooltip, dropdown etc.), you need to include the JS-file as well.

Answer (score 0):

in projects which rely on a lot javascript i always use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to load my dependencies for only what i need. you also can easily turn the JS plugins of bootstrap into AMD modules so you don't miss any dependencies after you configured them once.